# Magento 1.x - Custom JS/CSS not found

Tags: magento-1.8

I added these custom js and css file:

1. **skin/frontend/base/default/black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js**
2. **skin/frontend/base/default/black/NewsletterPopup/css/main.js**

Then I included them via my modules layout file

(**app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/black/newsletter_popup.phtml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>black/NewsletterPopup/css/main.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
<!-- ... -->
```

But a network analysis showed that the files could not be found and if I enter the link to the file directly into the URL then the "*404 Sorry page not found*" page shows up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

```
<action method="addJs">
    <script>black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js</script>
</action>
```

which actually targets the `{magentoroot}/js` folder, to

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <script>black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js</script>
</action>
```

which targets the skin folder.